# Containment in a subring of Rational Functions

Tags: abstract-algebra

This problem is from a former qualifying exam:

Let $p(x,y)$ be an irreducible polynomial with complex coefficients. Let $R$ be the subring of $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ consisting of all rational functions $\frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}$ such that $p(x,y)$ does not divide $g(x,y)$. We want to show that $R$ is a PID.

The solution given begins since $R$ is a subring of a field, it is a domain. Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$. Let $n\geq 0$ be minimal such that $p^{n}\in R$. Then $(p^{n})\subset I$. We claim that we have equality...

Why isn't $p(x)$ automatically contained in $R$?

Comment: If possible can you type the text in the image out? This helps to make the text searchable by other users. Thanks!